# SQL WHERE subquery with additional refinements?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to have a subquery in a WHERE statement with additional qualifiers? For instance, I have two tables on two different machines. I am trying to compare the tables and see which items only exist on one machine, but only a certain type of item. I only sync two types of items. I can run this query and it works:

```
select
ItemCode as style, 
ISNULL(U_certno,'') as U_certno,
U_he, ISNULL(U_mold,'N') as U_mold
from ITEMS Z
where
z.itemcode <> (SELECT distinct Q.style 
FROM remote.system.table Q where Q.style = Z.ItemCode)
```

That much works, I think. If I change the z.itemcode <> to z.itemcode =, I toggle between 0 results (sync is current), and all records. However, when I add:

```
and (z.U_he like 'y' or z.U_mold like 'y')
```

it gives me all items in the ITEMS table that have those two criteria, regardless of the subquery. I have tried all manners of parenthesis, to no avail. What am I doing wrong? I didn't bother trying a join, since I want dissimilar items, not matches. Any help would be appreciated. This is MSSQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Can you add the final query you are using?. Also, what's the point of using `LIKE` without wildcards?, that's fairly equivalent to `=`

Comment: I don't have a final query. All I have is what's above. Also, using LIKE is a bad habit of mine, heh, no real reason.

Comment: Well, then post the query that results when you add `and (z.U_he like 'y' or z.U_mold like 'y')`, I don't understand where are you adding that condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
ItemCode as style, 
ISNULL(U_certno,'') as U_certno,
U_he, ISNULL(U_mold,'N') as U_mold
from ITEMS Z
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from remote.system.table Q
  where Q.style = Z.ItemCode
)
  and 'y' IN (z.U_he, z.U_mold)
```

Comment: Awesome. You are my hero.